# Detect real "hard" character keys only

Tags: javascript

Is there any simple way to detect user keystrokes that result in character input? In other words, ignore all soft keys and modifier keys? This works but seems sort of hacky:

```
var keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode
if((keycode>=48 && keycode<=90) || (keycode>=96 && keycode<=111) || (keycode>=186 && keycode<=192) || (keycode>=219 && keycode<=222)){
    alert("realkey")
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you described what you were trying to achieve we could help more. Is this typing in a text input? Can you use the `keyup` event and see if the `.value` has changed as a result?

Comment: What you're doing looks like the best way to go. If you want something that doesn't look "hacky" you'll need a library like jQuery (which under the hood is hacky).

Comment: Sorry no its a contentEditable div. I'd hoped there was some easy way to check this range of keys but from the sounds of the comments there isn't....

Comment: I think you're using the best method.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use keypress events instead of keydown events.  See example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fmjh/6/ - or a non-jquery example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fmjh/11/

Comment: This is a cool solution. I can't fathom how to do it on contentEditable div tho?

Comment: Works just the same: http://jsfiddle.net/7fmjh/13/

Comment: What I mean is if its contenteditable then we'll need to append the keypress at the caret position rather than at the end of the div. I'm not actually using jQuery but the examples are great. thanks a lot

Comment: so...what exactly are you trying to do for YOUR page that you still can't do?  I'm assuming you don't want to append the word "keypress" every time they keypress haha.

Comment: This will not work in FireFox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.fromCharCode` in combination with a Regular Expression test as alernative:

```
var cando =  /[a-z0-9]/i
              .test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.charCode));
if( cando ){
    alert("realkey")
}
```

In the `RegExp` you can put all the characters you want to allow, in this case all a to z (case insensitive) and the digits 0 to 9. Best to use the `keypress` event here.

BTW, what kind of criterium is 'seeming sort of hacky'?

Comment: What about unicode?

Comment: "In the RegExp you can put all the characters you want to allow" ... So, put them between `/ ... /i`

Comment: typo: `String.fromCharCode`